# Files won't be read in GUI program, only in shell

Tags: python, word-cloud

Hey guys so I have a lengthy code here I need help with,
specifically: my end process is an assignment creating a word cloud, But I haven't even start at that point yet. As of now, I've been able to create the function of creating a frequency accumulator and my first GUI platform.

When running the program, the gui asks the user to type in the file name of their program. However, you can type gibberish or even leave it blank, click the transform file button, and it still opens up Shell and prompts the user for the text file name and then the number of words they want in the list.

I don't even want the 2nd part (asking how many words) but I didn't know another way of doing it for my frequency counter.

```
from graphics import *

##Deals with Frequency Accumulator##
def byFreq(pair):
    return pair[1]

##Function to allow user to upload their own text document##
def FileOpen(userPhrase):
    filename = input("Enter File Name (followed by .txt): ")
    text = open(filename, 'r').read()
    text = text.lower()
    for ch in ('!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_{}~'):
        text = text.replace(ch, " ")  
    words = text.split()

    counts = {}
    for w in words:
        counts[w] = counts.get(w,0) + 1
    n = eval(input("Output how many words?"))

    items = list(counts.items())
    items.sort(key=byFreq, reverse=True)
    for i in range(n):
        word, count = items[i]
        print("{0:<15}{1:>5}".format(word, count))

##This Function allows user to simply press button to see an example##
def Example():
    win = GraphWin("Word Cloud", 600, 600)

    file = open("econometrics.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8")
    text = file.read()
    text = text.lower()
    for ch in ('!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_{}~'):
        text = text.replace(ch, " ")  
    words = text.split()

    counts = {}
    for w in words:
        counts[w] = counts.get(w,0) + 1
    n = eval(input("Output how many words?"))

    items = list(counts.items())
    items.sort(key=byFreq, reverse=True)
    for i in range(n):
        word, count = items[i]
        print("{0:<15}{1:>5}".format(word, count))
#########################################################################
##Gold Boxes##
def boxes(gwin, pt1, pt2, words):

    button = Rectangle(pt1, pt2)
    button.setFill("gold")
    button.draw(gwin)

    #Middle of the box coordinates
    labelx = (pt1.getX() + pt2.getX())/2.0
    labely = (pt1.getY() + pt2.getY())/2.0

    #Labels
    label = Text(Point(labelx,labely),words)
    label.setFill("black")
    label.draw(gwin)

####GUI function#####  
def main():

    #Creates the actual GUI
    win = GraphWin("Word Cloud Prompt", 600, 600)

    #Box which user types into:
    inputBox = Entry(Point(300,150),50)
    inputBox.draw(win)

    #Gold Boxes at Top
    boxes(win, Point(220,300), Point(370,350), "Transform Text File")
    boxes(win, Point(220,400), Point(370,450), "Example text file")

    #Tells user what to do
    prompt = Text(Point(300,25),"Welcome to the Word Cloud program!")
    prompt.draw(win)

    prompt = Text(Point(300,125),"Enter your textfile name")
    prompt.draw(win)

    prompt = Text(Point(300,180),"Want to see our own file into a Word Cloud? Click below")
    prompt.draw(win)

    #display answer
    display = Text(Point(300, 500),"")
    display.draw(win)

    #User Clicks a box:
    pt = win.getMouse()

    #Store user info
    userPhrase = inputBox.getText()
    key = inputBox.getText()

    #Incase a button isn't clicked
    output = "No button was clicked, Please restart program"


    #Clicking the Transform Text File Button
    if pt.getY() >= 300 and pt.getY() <= 350:
        if pt.getX() >= 220 and pt.getX() <= 370:
            output = FileOpen(userPhrase)

    #Clicking the Example Text File Button
    if pt.getY() >= 400 and pt.getY() <= 450:
        if pt.getX() >= 220 and pt.getX() <= 370:
            output = Example()

    #State Answer
    display.setText(output)
    display.setFill("purple3")
    display.setStyle("bold")

    prompt.setText("Thank You! Click anywhere to close!")
    prompt.setFill("red")

    #closing program
    pt = win.getMouse()
    win.close()
main()
```

Comment: Correct the indentation in your code

Comment: where do I need to correct the indentation? @Leva7

Comment: In the code fields. The `def` part is not even in there, as well as the `main()` call. Pretty much the whole code is one indent level off

Comment: leva7, i see, i've edited the post

Comment: Having the first indent being one (1) space an the subsequent indents being four (4) spaces might run, but it does not feel Pythonic.

Comment: liturgist - Not Sure why it keeps coming out strange, therefore I deleted it and uploaded it to pastebin to keep things simple

Comment: Paste the code into your question, but this time highlight it and hit Ctrl-k to make it a code block.

Comment: Zondo - Is this how it should look now?

Comment: That looks good.  BTW, to ping someone, use @username.  I noticed your comment just because I happened to come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Editor's Note: I've modified some of the formatting for my ease of reading, but the function will be identical)

```
def FileOpen(userPhrase):
    """FileOpen allows users to upload their own text document."""

    filename = input("Enter File Name (followed by .txt): ")
    text = open(filename, 'r').read()
    text = text.lower()
    for ch in ('!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_{}~'):
        text = text.replace(ch, " ")
    words = text.split()

    counts = {}
    for w in words:
        counts[w] = counts.get(w, 0) + 1
    n = eval(input("Output how many words?"))

    items = list(counts.items())
    items.sort(key=byFreq, reverse=True)
    for i in range(n):
        word, count = items[i]
        print("{0:<15}{1:>5}".format(word, count))
```

This is the function we're concerned with. You call it with an argument `userPhrase` that comes from a gui text entry field, but then you never *use* `userPhrase` anywhere in the function. Consider instead:

```
def file_open(userPhrase=None):
    # file_open is lowercase and snake_case for PEP8
    # userPhrase=None to make it an optional argument

    filename = userPhrase if userPhrase is not None else \
               input("Enter file name (including extension): ")
    ...
```

Then you'll have to call it differently if you want `file_open` to prompt for a filename if not given one.

```
def main():

    ...

    if 300 <= pt.getY() <= 350 and 220 <= pt.getX() <= 370:
        # you can chain conditionals as above. It makes it much easier to read!
        # `a <= N <= b` is easily read as `N is between a and b`

        userPhrase = inputBox.getText()
        if userPhrase.strip():  # if there's something there
            file_open(userPhrase)
        else:
            file_open()
```

Comment: Thanks @Adam Smith! That works well!

Comment: @Jim the second part of your question (how to create a word cloud) seems to be a separate question from "Why doesn't my code respect the GUI" and should be asked as such.

Comment: For what it's worth, `eval(input(...))` is about the worst line you could ever have in your code. If your user types something malicious, Python interprets it as valid code, e.g. `import os; [os.unlink(f) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:\") for f in files]` just deleted everything on your computer.

Comment: sort of a question dealing with the same thing. I deleted these lines:
`n = eval(input(howmanywords))
for i in range(n):
 word, count = items[i]
        print("{0:<15}{1:>5}".format(word, count))`
Since I'm ultimately creating a Word Cloud, will i eventually be able to say print(items) to create the word graphic in a new window? Basically what I'm asking is, will the info be stored in Items for as long as the program is running

Comment: @Jim short answer: No. Long answer: `items` is scoped to the `open_file`, so as soon as the function is exited it will be handed over to the garbage collector and unlinked. Efficient answer: use a class.